# Perl Frequency sorting and other things

Tags: perl, sorting, printing, cpu-word, frequency

Edit:

So I got the script working great with all your help, so thanks a lot.

I'm also trying to figure out how I can keep the standard input choice but still be able to use a command-line "start" aswell,

I want both to be able to start it by for ex. "perl wfreq.pl" and it then asks the user what file, but I also want to be able to start it by saying "perl wfreq.pl example.txt" and then it shouldnt ask for the user input.

Is this possible?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use warnings;

print "Please enter the name of the file: \n" ;
$file = <STDIN>;
chop $file;


open(my $DATA, "<:utf8", $file) or die "Oops!!: $!";
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

while(<$DATA>) {                          
    tr/A-Za-z//cs;
    s/[;:()".,!?]/ /gio;                   
    foreach $word (split(' ', lc $_)) {  
    $freq{$word}++;                  
     }
}
foreach $word (sort { $freq{$b} <=> $freq{$a} } keys %freq) {           
   @fr = (@fr, $freq{$word});
   @ord = (@ord, $word);        
}
for ($v =0; $v < 10; $v++){
print " $fr[$v] | $ord[$v]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [MVS wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7804486#7804655), you need to use the "spaceship" `<=>` operator and sort not keys, but values.
Here's example that should work:

Change

```
foreach $word (sort keys %freq) {        
    print "$word $freq{$word}\n";        
}
```

To

```
foreach $word (sort { $freq{$a} <=> $freq{$b} } keys %freq) {        
    print "$word $freq{$word}\n";
}
```

[perldoc -f sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) contains just the same example at lines 23-27 of code snippet.

Talking about encoding: [utf8 pragma documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) says to use it for

> enable/disable UTF-8 (or UTF-EBCDIC) in source code

To enable UTF-8 in file input you need to open file in specific mode (using specific layer) and apply 'utf8' layer to STDOUT:

```
open(my $DATA, "<:utf8", $file) or die "Oops!!: $!";
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
```

For more information about `:utf8` and other IO Layers you can read

1. [:utf8 layer description](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html#DESCRIPTION)
2. [perldoc -f open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
3. [perldoc -f binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html)

Comment: Thanks alot, works just fine now with the sorting.
Still having trouble with the open (DATA, "<:utf8", $file) or die "Oops!!: $!"; I get the error Filehandle DATA opened only for output at wfreq2.pl line 14. I'll get on those links you posted and see if I can find the answer somewhere there!

Comment: don't use DATA. Use something like: open( my $data, "<:utf8", $filename) or die "ops: $!";

Comment: Just what @ØyvindSkaar wrote. My fault, I copied code from original snippet without any control.

Comment: Trying;

open (my $data, "<:utf8", "$file") or die "Oops!!: $!";


while(<$data>) {

and the output still doesnt show "åäö" :(

Comment: Ok, this is because your STDOUT filehandle, which represents standart output is not in utf8 mode.
I updated my answer. Also here's complete utf8 example that should work on your side (I houpe your terminal is utf8 too):

    `echo "åäö" > test.txt;`
    `perl -e 'open my $file, "<:utf8", "test.txt"; binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; print <$file>'`

Comment: Any idea on how to handle the limitation of the foreach loop to a max of 10 times? I guess I need a counter in there somewhere and a stop value that stops after 10 times.

Comment: I know I could possably do this with arrays instead and just limit how many times it should print, But that's not what I need to do, I need to limit the loop somehow.

Comment: You really need to store sorted keys in array. There's few way to achieve this, see my gist: https://gist.github.com/1295774

Answer (score 1):

`sort keys` will sort by the keys of the hash, which are the words themselves.  Instead, you'll want to sort by the values instead.  Have a look at the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) to help you (in particular, the parts about the "spaceship operator" `<=>`).

To put the numbers before the words, just switch `$word` and `$freq{$word}` in the `print` statement.

As for returning only the top 10 results, try a counter inside your `foreach` loop (and the `break` statement).

For UTF-8 characters, your `use utf8` should be good enough to enable them, but if you're encountering problems, [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the way it prints so the numbers is first, still having problems with the sorting with the <=> operator, but I'll try more and see if I can get it right. the "use utf8" isnt working properly atm, some words with åäö isnt is stripped from that letter in the result i get in Terminal. I'll have a look at that link and see if anything helps.

Comment: `use utf8` just tells perl that the _source code_ uses UTF-8. It has no effect on data read from or returned to the terminal, files, etc. @user998836, if you edit your question to show some examples of your UTF-8 input and the resulting output, we'll be better able to help you with that problem.

Comment: Right now the input file consist of a lot of swedish names, one is "Åke" and it's mentioned three times in the text right now, so the result I get in terminal is "3 ke" so it strippes the swedish "å" in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bunch of neat things in Perl:

```
perl -CS -F\\PL+ -alne'$f{lc$_}++for@F}{print"$f{$_} $_"for sort{$f{$b}<=>$f{$a}}keys%f'
```

See `perlrun(1)` for more details.

Comment: Why mine answer is down-voted without any comment even it perfectly solving problem? It sets utf8 mode if input and output, it detect words in right way, it sorts right, ... It also gives perfect direction what to look for. It pointed out to perlrun manual where one can easily find what each switch do, each switch then point out to another part for perl documentation where one can found each trick I used in mine solution. Figuring out what it does will learn you more about perl than week of plain looking into manual or asking questions on forums.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with your golf-style formatting. Also, lack of explanations is frowned upon by some. I am curious myself about your `-F` pattern. `\\PL+`?

Comment: Looks great, I personally didn't downrank it, it's a bit more complicated than what I was looking for but it seems Perl has a lot of versatility.

Comment: @TLP: `perlrecharclass(1)` it is inverted unicode Letter class.

Comment: @FictionFighter I don't understand why you find it *more complicated* when it does same things as your code but more versatile and in some edge case also more *correct* way. Mine code do same things: read lines from input, split to words, count them and print sorted result. Read lines and and split them is very common task so there is switch `-a` and `-n` for it. `-F` defines how to split words and `-CS` switches on unicode support. `}{` most tricky thing there but if you will read `-n` switch documentation carefully it is pretty obvious. `-l` and `-e` are well documented in `perlrun(1)` too.

Comment: @Hynek - I didn't DV but considered to, because (1) The answer did NOT contain explanation from your last comment; and (2) it did NOT contain a note that Golf-style code like this is for quick/dirty task solving and not serious development. It's code like this that causes senior management to decide against using Perl since nobody but two old time gurus can read it. Providing golfy answers is fine, as long as a naive newbie OP is given sufficient info to understand the downsides of golfing.

Comment: @Hynek - also, you're NOT using a bunch of neat things in "Perl", but a bunch of neat things in "perl" (e.g. command line interpeter). While they ARE undoubtedly "neat", your answer is localized to situations where one-liner is acceptable (e.g. not web development; not large scale system).